# Creating new bash session with different user in the same window

Tags: bash, unix

How can I create a new bash session with different logged user in the same window?

Should be one command as far as I understood.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the current user with the `su` command:

```
su USERNAME
```

If you need a login shell use the `-l` option

Comment: And maybe better `su -` so that just `su` ([more info](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/71481-what-difference-between-su-su.html#post372585))

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, that's the same as `-l`. Have mentioned this. But thx, I didn't know that `-` and `-l` are the same :)

Comment: @hek2mgl me neither :) !!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a new session with a different user with:

```
su - <username>
```

You then get a session as the new user and the PATH specific to that user.

you can return to your old session by typing:

```
exit
```

Comment: Remember tha the hyphen keeps your environment loaded.